# Print number without spaces using java.util.logging?

Tags: java, vert.x, java.util.logging

I am currently using Vertx's default logging tool : `java.utils.logging`.

I have a variable defined as follow : `private static int port = 8600;`

This line :

```
logger.info("Server is now listening on port {0}", port);
```

gives the following output :

```
[2018-05-29 16:00:54] [INFOS  ] Server is now listening on port 8 600
```

I find the space in `8 600` disturbing, as ports are usually not written with spaces.

How can I make my logger print port number as : `8600` and not `8 600`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `{0,number,#}` instead of `{0}`.

Edit: More info: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html

Comment: Works fine. I will accept your answer as soon as I will be able to. Thanks!